# "QuantumRenderer-" 0 for JavaFX font

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I have tried multiple solutions on net and some saying me as this could be the hardware acceleration issues. I applied all of those, and also tried other solutions mentioned in Stack Overflow, but failed to get solution.

Issue is application crashed randomly. Logs are below

```
Thread 19 Crashed:: Java: QuantumRenderer-0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20347462 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20375610 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff202c8720 abort + 120
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001062b35c1 os::abort(bool) + 25
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001063dfff6 VMError::report_and_die() + 2306
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001062b5206 JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001062b144b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
7   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff203b9d7d _sigtramp + 29
8   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff2019c127 free + 107
9   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff219a6b43 TFont::GetScaledMatrix() const + 55
10  com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff21a0040e TFont::CreatePathForGlyph(unsigned short, CGAffineTransform const*) const + 146
11  com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff21a00355 CTFontCreatePathForGlyph + 41
12  libjavafx_font.dylib            0x00000001123cf4d0 Java_com_sun_javafx_font_coretext_OS_CTFontCreatePathForGlyph + 224
13  ???                             0x000000011439a9ce 0 + 4634290638
14  ???                             0x0000000115327300 0 + 4650595072
```

Comment: Share more logs. What exactly the input is and what you are trying to acheive

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?